# How to solve this php associative array push

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-push

I have an array like below:

```
$storedItem = ['item_id' => $ItemInfo['ItemId'], 'qty' => [], 'price' => $item->price, 'size' => [], 'produ' => [], 'item' => $item];
```

I have 2 string variables called `$size` and `$quantity`.

I need to push them into produ array. Then I used

```
> array_push($storedItem['produ'], $size);
```

But, the thing is I need to push `$size` and `$quantity` several times into produ array. But, when I use `array_push` again & again, it overwrite the array.

But, what I want like below.

```
$storedItem['produ'] = [];
$storedItem['produ'][0] => 0 => $size, 1=>$quantity
$storedItem['produ'][1] => 0 => $size, 1=>$quantity
$storedItem['produ'][2] => 0 => $size, 1=>$quantity
```

How can I do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solve your problem:

```php
$storedItem['produ'][] = [$size, $quantity];
```